# Java Threads GDB

Tags: java, multithreading, gdb

I'm getting a null pointer exception even if i already started the thread. **Is there some other way to setcommands or pass arguments to a running thread?**

```
public class MainClass{
    public static void main(String [ ] args)
    {
        try{
            GDBpipeWriter g = new GDBpipeWriter();
            new Thread(g).start();
            // Set commands
            g.setcommand("run");
            g.setcommand("list");
            g.setcommand("list 10,20");
        }catch(NullPointerException e){
        }
    }
}


public class GDBpipeWriter implements Runnable{
    public volatile String command;
    PrintWriter stdin;
    public void setcommand(String com){
        this.command = com;
        stdin.println(command);
    }
    public void run(){
        Process p = null;
        try {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("gdb a.out --interpreter=console");
            new Thread(new SyncPipe(p.getErrorStream(), System.err)).start();
            new Thread(new SyncPipe(p.getInputStream(), System.out)).start();
            stdin = new PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream());

            stdin.flush();
            stdin.println("break 4");
            stdin.flush();
            stdin.println("break 10");
            stdin.flush();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


class SyncPipe implements Runnable
{
    public SyncPipe(InputStream istrm, OutputStream ostrm) {
        istrm_ = istrm;
        ostrm_ = ostrm;
    }
    public void run() {
        try
        {
            final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            for (int length = 0; (length = istrm_.read(buffer)) != -1; )
            {
                ostrm_.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private final OutputStream ostrm_;
    private final InputStream istrm_;
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe a "race condition", so stdin is not defined when you reach the first setcommand() call.
You call setcommand from main(), but stdin is not set already.

**Update**

You ask now how to do this. There are many ways to get that working. Here only one proposal:

Let setcommand() set the command member and nothing more. In the run() method put a while loop. in the while loop wait that command get set, send comand to the stream and reset command to null. Optional sleep() some ms, then continue the loop. HTH.